# Hide div with specific content in jquery

Tags: jquery

Is possible hide div .one with jquery if content is the next?

```
<div class="one">
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div class="titulo"></div>
        <div class="contenido"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My php code is this:

```
<div class="one" style="background-color:<?php echo esc_url( of_get_option( 'primary_color' ) ); ?>;color:#FFFFFF;">
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div class="titulo"><?php the_field('titulo_caja_superior'); ?></div>
    <div class="contenido"><?php the_field('cajaizquno'); ?></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "don't have content?". Text inside?

Comment: This question is unclear. Can you update your post and ask a better question?

Comment: next html mean show the next dom element ah?

Comment: @Sudharsan I think he mean "the following html". How do you fill the html with content?

Comment: Question improve, i think...
and thanks people. Many negative votes for someone who speaks poor English helpful. I tried to express myself best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    $('div.titulo:empty+div.contenido:empty').parents('div.one').hide();
```

would hide the entire thing if both `titulo` and `contenido` were empty.

Comment: really thanks for your help @John C. i'm going to try it

Comment: yeah! it works perfect!
<script>
       jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('div.titulo:empty+div.contenido:empty').parents('div.one').hide();
       });
       </script>

Comment: glad I could help! You could also probably do it in the php if you wanted...